# Relate Backlog items to Features

Tags: tfs

How to relate Backlog items to Feature or how to configure states so that moving feature to another state related backlog items would move together with the feature? The boards of Features and backlog items have the same states.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible if you want to do something like the chain action between work items, e.g for the  linked/associated work items, change the state of one of them, then all the work items have the same action (change to the same state).

In tfs process with different WITs you can track different types of work—such as product backlog items, tasks, bugs, and more.  By default in Scrum process `Feature` and `Product Backlog Item` are in different levels, they track different types of work... Please see [Scrum process work item types and workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/scrum-process-workflow?toc=/azure/devops/boards/work-items/toc.json&bc=/azure/devops/boards/work-items/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=vsts) for details.